# Global Variable not changing value in function

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a nodejs app and I am trying to pass a value called membership to a page. I initialize it and try to update its value in a function but the output doesn't change. It still outputs 0. Please I need help

```
app.get("/",(req,res)=>{
    var membershipStrength = 0;
    memberData.findAll()
        .then(members =>{
            // console.log(members.length);
            membershipStrength = members.length;
            console.log(membershipStrength);
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log("Error fetching members data: ", err);
        });
    console.log(membershipStrength);
    return res.render("index",
        {
        page: "Admin",
        membershipStrength: membershipStrength,
        // tableData : global.dataOut
        }
    );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You're calling the `render` function before the call to `findAll` completes. Thus, when your server responds to the HTTP request, it still has the original value of `membershipStrength` in it.

You need to put the call to `render` inside the `then` handler:

```
app.get("/",(req,res)=>{
    var membershipStrength = 0;
    return memberData.findAll()
        .then(members =>{
            // console.log(members.length);
            membershipStrength = members.length;
            console.log(membershipStrength);
            return res.render("index",
            {
              page: "Admin",
              membershipStrength: membershipStrength,
              // tableData : global.dataOut
            }
            );
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log("Error fetching members data: ", err);
        });

});
```